# Python поиск определённого кадра в видео

Tags: python

Открыл видео с помощью библиотеки MoviePy. Мне необходимо узнать, на каких секундах располагается определённый кадр, который повторяется несколько раз в видео. Например, видео длится 42 секунды. Кадр располагается на 7-й и 32-й секундах. Нужно найти эти таймкоды. Можно использовать любую библиотеку, не знаю, можно ли сделать это с использованием MoviePy

```
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip('1.mp4')
video = video.subclip(0, video.duration)
video.write_videofile('2.mp4', fps=30)
```